# Laravel 5.2 uploaded images are broken

Tags: php, image, laravel

I'm doing an app in Laravel 5.2 where I can upload users pictures to public on their own profiles.

Thing is, when a move the file to destination path, file is created but content is missing because I cannot open it.

I share a screenshot with the code and the imagen from windows explorer...
[image]

Any advice?

Comment: The real question is how did that file know to get uploaded into the `member` directory?!

Comment: The PHP package on the Windows server must be compiled with the –enable-zend-multibyte option. This issue is detailed in [PHP bug report #22108](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22108)

Comment: Ohgodwhy, to keep files there is easy, just you have to config where to keep public files and that's it. In my case public_html is shared with wordpress so /member is the public folder for laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I got fix the problem but couldn't use Input class from Laravel, should use GD Library to get move correctly the image.
[image]